# Is it possible to use 2 versions of the same dependency in gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using retrofit 1.9 and I have few requests where it would be more efficient to use retrofit 2+. As there are too many requests (and they works perfectly) it will take excessive time to transfer them from 1.9 to 2+. Thus, is there possibility to use both versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer version will be picked and used in the project.

No, this is not possible. One of the versions will be ignored because this is how gradle [dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution) algorithm works.

It also seems that it should not work with any build tool (maven, ant..).